# Exclude togglz-console from spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, toggle

I'd like to exclude the toggle-console from being included in the spring-security auth process: I want to access it on the management port without auth. Despite adding matchers to the requestMatchers in my WebSecurityConfig the console is always  blocked by the login prompt.

The SecurityFilterChain bean I have:

```java
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      return http
              .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                      .requestMatchers("/actuator",
                              "/actuator/*",
                              "/togglz-console",
                              "/togglz-console/**",
                              "/togglz*",
                              "/togglz**"
                      )
                      .permitAll()
                      .anyRequest()
                      .authenticated()
              )
              .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
              .formLogin(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)
              .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll)
              .build();
  }
```

in application.properties I have the following:

```yaml
togglz:
  enabled:
    true
  features:
    CHEEKY_GREETING:
      enabled: false
  console:
    secured: false
    use-management-port: true
  endpoint:
    enabled: true
    id: togglz
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'togglz, health'
  server:
    port: 8081
```

My project has the following dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}
ext {
    togglz_version = "4.0.1"
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-spring-boot-starter:${togglz_version}")
    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-console:${togglz_version}")
}
```

I tried adding the `togglz-security-spring-boot-starter` too, but made no change.

Code all on a branch here: https://github.com/robjwilkins/showcase/tree/add/togglz

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong? thanks

Comment: The magic for me here was to expose `togglz` as a management endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that when the request for `/togglz-console` is checked by `PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping` it looks at

```
ServletRequestPathUtils.getParsedRequestPath(request).pathWithinApplication()
```

The request path *is* `/togglz-console`, however `pathWithinApplication()` returns `""`. For some reason `/togglz-console` is not being considered 'part of the application' (perhaps because it's being provided as a 3rd party add-on).

A solution to this is to add special `requestMatcher`, which can be configured to look at the whole request path, and ignore the `pathWithinApplication`.

for example:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> 
         requests
             .requestMatchers(customMatcher("/togglz-console"),
                              customMatcher("/togglz-console/*"))
             .permitAll()
             .requestMatchers("/public")
             .permitAll()
             .anyRequest()
             .authenticated()
             .formLogin(withDefaults())
             .build();
}

private RequestMatcher customMatcher(String pattern) {
    return request -> {
        var matcher = new PathPatternParser().parse(pattern);
        var path = ServletRequestPathUtils.parseAndCache(request);
        return matcher.matches(path);
    };
}
```